# Not able to get any output from awk command in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to write a shell script to get certain data from below sample logs..

Below is a sample log:

```
2014-07-08 16:08:25,684:        |ABC_130|1|10123ffffff2|P|489440201
2014-07-08 17:08:25,684:        |ABC_130|1|aaaaaxxxxaab|P|489440201
2014-07-08 19:08:25,684:        |ABC_130|1|aaaaababbaab|P|489440201
```

Below is a part of the script where I am facing issue, the issue I am facing is that the awk command doesn't give any output.

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE_HOUR="`date -d '1 hour ago' "+%Y-%m-%d %H"`"

awk -F ":" '{if ($1='"$DATE_HOUR"') print $0}' log.txt
```

Comment: Shell variables don't expand within single quotes (which you've quoted the entire awk script with). Use `-v` to pass the shell variable to awk as an awk variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use shell variable like that in awk. Use `-v name=val`:

```
awk -F ":" -v dt="$DATE_HOUR" '$1==dt' log.txt
```

btw I reduced your awk command to `'$1==dt'` since `print $0` is **default action** and also if condition can be moved out of curly braces.